# How to point the subdomain to Main domain sub folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, vesta

I have the site domain.com and creates the need `subdomain.domain.com` that points to the directory `domain.com/public_html/subdomain`

How do I do that?

The `subdomain` folder must be within the `public_html` folder `domain.com`

The vestaCP possesses the possilidade to choose the root folder of the `subdomain`?

Sorry for my bad English.

**Simply put:**

I need it:

```
sub.domain.com> /home/user/web/domain.com/public_html/subdomain
```

No:

```
sub.domain.com> /home/user/web/sub.domain.com/public_html
```

Answer (score -1):

I always solve it by one of this 2 ways (each of them has advantages and disadvantages):

1. I redirect the subdomain by .htaccess file to the folder inder the main domain. So i just add `Redirect 301 / http://example.com/subfolder` to the `.htaccess` file of subdomain. It's classic unmasked redirection.
2. I make a PHP file index.php in `/home/user/web/sub.domain.com/public_html` folder with this content: `<?php print file_get_contents("https://example.com/subdomain/"); ?>` and in folder `/home/user/web/example.com/public_html/subdomain` is website. Phe PHP file displays the whole content of website on main domain folder.

None of them is the real solution, it's just a how to hack it, but I hope it will be useful